# I got the message "Some Error!" when pay through PayPal on Google In-app purchase

Tags: android, paypal, in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase

I have implemented the In-app purchase functionality in my android application when I am going to purchase the item then all the method options shows on Google in app purchase are working but when i have purchase through PayPal then found the Error message "Some Error!". Please give me the solution, how to manage this error.

I have attached the screenshot of my purchasing screen. [image]

Comment: Ok I have got the solution.